# Ruby - Including two modules that both have a sub-module with the same name

Tags: ruby, oop, module

I have two modules, `Foo` and `Bar`. Each has a namespaced module called `Errors` that contains error classes as so:

```
module Foo
  module Errors
    class FooError < StandardError
      def initialize
        super "I'm a FooError"
      end
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  module Errors
    class BarError < StandardError
      def initialize
        super "I'm a BarError"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to `include` both of these modules in my class called `Baz` and be able to access both `Errors` modules. As so:

```
class Baz
  include Foo
  include Bar

  p Errors::FooError.new
  p Errors::BarError.new
end
```

Ruby throws an error `uninitialized constant Bar::Errors::FooError` when trying to instantiate `FooError` but not for `BarError`.

Am I understanding correctly that the `Bar::Errors` module is overwriting the `Foo:Errors` module? How do I prevent that from happening/accomplish being able to reference both types of errors from within `Baz`?

Thanks!

Comment: You've only got one namespace to work with at any given time. Why are you deliberately calling `include` on two things that conflict? It's better to avoid that and just refer to them by their long, formal names.

Comment: I'm guessing `Foo` and `Bar` would normally have more in them than just the conflicting modules.

Comment: Just to piggyback on @tadman 's answer, if you really need to set it up this way, you'd need to call them more explicitly.  Like: `p Foo::Errors::BarError.new`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. To add some context, both `Foo` and `Bar` are concerns that deal with consuming two different APIs. The class `Baz` is an entity that can consume both of these APIs. Look's like @Max answer about renaming them to `FooErrors` and `BarErrors` is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always rename modules to not conflict:

```
Foo::FooErrors = Foo::Errors
Bar::BarErrors = Bar::Errors
```

Or you could skip the conflicting modules and go straight to including the error classes you want:

```
class Baz
  include Foo::Errors
  include Bar::Errors
end
```

Or don't bother including anything and use the full names:

```
p Foo::Errors::FooError.new
p Bar::Errors::BarError.new
```

In my opinion, `include` is too often used as a convenience method to avoid typing module names. This usage is not really necessary and can introduce errors (as you've seen) or ambiguity. There are some things that you can *only* accomplish using `include` (like adding instance methods from a module), but most uses I see don't fall in that camp.

Comment: Thanks @Max. I use include to make the methods defined in `Foo` and `Bar` available to `Baz` (and then to a bunch of other 'entiities' similiar to `Baz`). Seems like renaming them as you have shown in your first example is the easiest resolution.

Comment: This is certainly one way to do it, but it is kind of awkward to be defining constants in another namespace like that. This sort of interdependency creates a lot of havoc if you make it a habit. Your second and third approaches are a lot better.